# Finding Glue Job Name with only a job run id

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a way of getting the name of the Glue Job that produced the log stream given only the jrid?

The only parameters that I can work with are the jrid and the log group name.

I know I can pull all the glue jobs and then go through them individually until I find the glue job that has that specific jrid but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to get from Job Run ID to Job Name.

You'll probably need to:

- Call `list_jobs()` to get all Job Names
- For each Job, call `get_job_run()`
- Look for a batching `Id` in the response

Comment: I was worried I would have to do something like this. Thank you!